# Values in array are updated correctly but a different component is being removed

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am creating a component that can hold multiple `Value` components. User is able to add as many as he wants. First value (component) can not be deleted as it does not have a remove button next to itself. Whenever I add add 2 new `Value` components I am able to input name and description for that value. I emit input event so the parent component could keep all values from all the components. Whenever I click remove button next to a value it calls parent method, so it could be removed from the values list. It gets removed correctly, I print the updated list so I can see that the correct value is removed. However, it removes the last component and not the one I clicked remove button for. The list is correct but the components that are being created based on that list are not and it even contains old value. I can't see what I am doing wrong.

`ParentComponent`

```
<div v-for="(component, index) in components" v-bind:key="index">
    <Value
        class="value"
        :valueIndex="index"
        v-model="components[index]"
        :id="'value_' + index"
        :isFirst="index === 0"
     ></Value>
</div>

export default {
    name: "Values",
    components: {
        Value
    },
    data() {
        return {
            components: [{
                name: "",
                description: ""
            }],
            componentsCount: 1
        }
    },
    methods: {
        addValue() {
            this.components.push({
                name: "",
                description: ""
            });
        },
        removeValue(valueIndex) {
            console.log(valueIndex);
            console.log(this.components[valueIndex]);
            this.components.splice(valueIndex, 1);
        }
    }
```

`ValueComponent`

```
<b-col md="4" sm="12">
     <input
         type="text"
         class="value-input"
         v-model="buffer.name"
         :name="'description_' + (this.valueIndex + 1)"
         :placeholder="'Description ' + (this.valueIndex + 1)"
         @input="$emit('input', buffer)"
     >
</b-col>
<b-col v-if="isFirst" md="8" sm="12">
    <input
        type="text"
        class="value-input"
        v-model="buffer.description"
        :name="'description_' + (this.valueIndex + 1)"
        :placeholder="'Description ' + (this.valueIndex + 1)"
        @input="$emit('input', buffer)"
    >
</b-col>
<b-col v-else md="8" sm="10">
    <b-row>
        <b-col sm="10">
             <input
                  type="text"
                  class="value-input"
                  v-model="buffer.description"
                  :name="'description_' + (this.valueIndex + 1)"
                  :placeholder="'Description ' + (this.valueIndex + 1)"
                  @input="$emit('input', buffer)"
             >
         </b-col>
         <b-col sm="2">
             <button class="garbage-button" @click="removeValue()">
                  <img src="../../assets/bin.svg">
             </button>
         </b-col>
     </b-row>
</b-col>

     export default {
            name: "Value",
            props: {
                valueIndex: {
                    type: Number,
                    required: true
                },
                isFirst: {
                    type: Boolean,
                    required: true
                }
            },
            data() {
                return {
                    buffer: Object.assign({}, this.value)
                }
            },
            methods: {
                removeValue() {
                    this.$parent.removeValue(this.valueIndex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Tell me if you need more of my code or the problem is not explained well.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem before. 
Somehow, it was getting confused about the positions and was deleting the wrong one.

What worked for me was using unique identifiers.
I used [uuidv4](https://npmjs.com/package/uuidv4) and it fixed this problem. This creates unique keys that you can use to bind to your items.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to the [in-place-patch](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Maintaining-State) functionality of vue together as using the index as `key`, which is not effective in this case, use another unique key if available (for example an `id` like mentioned in other answer). Because of the previous and you are assigning the value to `buffer` in child only once, thus the value is not reflected when change happens. You can solve this by using `watch` and modify `buffer` accordingly when changes happen in your v-for:

```js
props: {
  // ...
  value: {
    type: Object,
    default: () => {
      return {};
    }
  }
},
data() {
  return {
    buffer: Object.assign({}, this.value)
  };
},
watch: {
  value(val) {
    this.buffer = val;
  }
}
```

**[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-field-m2iie?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue)**

Worth mentioning still, that actually the right item is being deleted, value is just not updating due to how Vue handles v-for.